# send json to server(android)

Tags: java, android, json

Sorry for my english. I cant send json to server. I have error:

> {"message":"Customer data is empty!","status":"error"}

Its my example, hov i must send json:

> JSON example:

```
{
  "company_id": "1",
  "phones": [
    "380000505050"
  ],
  "photo": "/files/clients_photos/tmp/484629825.JPG",
  "name": "sdfsdfdsf",
  "birthdate": "10.02.2014",
  "email": "sdf@sdf.ff",
  "cars": {
    "1": {
      "car_brand_id": "9",
      "car_model_id": "856",
      "number": "AE5884AH",
      "photo": "/files/clients_photos/tmp/484629824.JPG"
    }
  }
}
```

This is link, where i send json http://crm.pavlun.info/api/register

This is my code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            JSONParser operationLink = new JSONParser();

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postInform = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postInform.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company_id", "2"));
            postInform.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phones", "380950466589"));
            postInform.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Alexy"));
            postInform.add(new BasicNameValuePair("birthdate", "12.03.2014"));
            postInform.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "nesalexy@mail.ru"));
            postInform.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo", "/files/clients_photos/tmp/484629825.JPG"));

            JSONObject registration = null;

            try {
                Log.e("perform link", postInform.toString()); //its output [company_id=2, phones=380950466589, name=Alexy, birthdate=12.03.2014, email=nesalexy@mail.ru, photo=/files/clients_photos/tmp/484629825.JPG]

                registration = operationLink.makeHttpRequest(registrationURL, "POST", postInform);
                Log.e("Link", registration.toString()); //its output {"message":"Customer data is empty!","status":"error"}
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

This is JSONparser class:

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) throws JSONException {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String 
        return jObj; 
        //return new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));

    }
}
```

Comment: You should check the documentation of the server that you're communicating with to see what this error means and what can cause it.

Comment: You'r absolutely doing a wrong. If you want to send a json data to sever then you need to put your data to `JSONObject` if your tag start with `JSONObject` and if it `JSONArray` then also put data in that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had the same problem previously, strangely enough, servers differ in the way they accept post data.

here is an example

the following method works for a `jetty` server but not `Play`:

```
public static void sendPost(String data,String url) throws Exception{

    org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient client = new org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient();
    org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost post = new org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost(url);
    org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity entity = new org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity(data.toString());
    post.setEntity(entity);
    client.execute(post);

}
```

the followig method works for `Play` server but not `jetty`:

```
public static void sendPostV2(String data, String url) throws Exception{

    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient client = 
            new org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient();
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod method = 
            new org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod(url);
     method.addParameter("data", data);
     client.executeMethod(method);
     method.releaseConnection();

}
```

we still haven't figured out why, but oh well whatever works baby.

in your case please feel free to use any of the following method (note download the required apache packages). hopefully one of them works for you.